# TestClient Fastapi tests returns 522 error

Tags: python, testing, fastapi

I am testing my fastapi application

```
# router = APIRouter()
client = TestClient(router)

def test():
    headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'authorization': 'token',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    json = {"data": "data", "count": 2}
    response = client.post("/api", headers=headers, json=json)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

My API works on the site, but here I get an error 522, what can this mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `TestClient` for an `APIRouter`, you have to use the `FastAPI` instance.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot